# Is there a way to add windows right click menu for a specifical exe file?

Tags: contextmenu, exe

I just want to know is there a way to add context menu item for my application(.exe file)? For example, there is an exe file -- "test.exe". When right click it, show a content menu with an item--"do it". When click others exe files, "do it" shouldn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Targeting a specific file is a little complicated since context menus are primarily designed to operate on file type, but you can do this using with a type of registry entry called [Advanced Query Syntax (MSDN link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx#dynamic_behavior).

1. open RegEdit to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell`
2. create a new key (folder) named `Do It`
3. add a new String Value named `AppliesTo` in the `Do It` key
4. set the `AppliesTo` value to `System.ItemName:"test.exe"`
5. create a `Command` key under `Do It`
6. change the `(Default)` value to your exe pathname (with any parameters)
7. close RegEdit, the changes happen immediately

Note this will show the "Do It" command for *any* file or folder that has "test.exe" in the name. I'm not sure you can get any more specific than this short of writing, installing, and registering a shell handler extension program. A file named "not_a_test.exe" would also get the "Do It" command -- and choosing it would run your real test.exe (since the `Command` default value points there).

Comment: Thanks a lot, McGuireV10. That's work for me after I change the "AppliesTo" value to 'System.ItemName:"test"'(without ".exe").